# Why can't travel through a closed timelike curve violate the Novikov self-consistency principle?

Tags: general-relativity, causality, time-travel, closed-timelike-curve

The Novikov self-consistency principle prevents a paradox in which a billiard ball is sent to its past through a closed timelike curve (allowed under general relativity) such that it collides with its past self and prevents it from entering.

Imagine a setup where the ball, as soon as it exits in the past, hits a switch that closes a gate across the entrance. What's to stop that from creating a paradox? There's no alternate trajectory for the ball that would make it consistent; the switch can be a plate that covers the exit so that the ball can't avoid hitting it.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost closed questions. Your other question already had 2 reopen votes, but you interrupted the reopen process by deleting it.

Comment: What stops a clock from running backwards? The fact that you would have to change the state of the entire remaining universe to accomplish that.

Comment: @ACuriousMind OK, I undeleted the first one. Should do anything with this one?

Comment: Duplicates in this forum are a no no (just like my "no's were duplicated)